# How to orchestrate 30 containers on 3 vps and set 1 ip for them

Tags: docker, kubernetes, load-balancing, orchestration, horizontal-scaling

I want to setup 10 containers on 3 vps (30 containers in sum) and I want to make them look like one big server (load balance).
I want them to have ONE IP so that I can set this for the dns of my website domain name. Where should I read all about this?
What tools I need to know about? Does for example kubernetes do this for me?

I have been reading all of containers orchestration websites but they seem to just deviated me. They just talk about business side not the technical part.

Any help would be appreciated. Even suggestion for a book is great.

Comment: Are you looking to do this using a cloud provider like AWS or Azure? If so they offer very simplified offerings that will take the burden of managing infrastructure off your shoulders. e.g AWS ECS can run containers for you without the hassle of orchestration. You can use an ELB for the single IP requirement.

If you are trying to do this in your own network using your own network, Kubernetes can help but it will be a lot more work. Mesos/Marathon can also run containers for you.

Comment: No I dont want to use Managed cloud provider. I have 3 Ubuntu 14.04 VPS. I want to do it all manually. Can you show me a simple overview of how the steps would be?

Comment: In simplistic terms you would need to setup a Kubernetes cluster, then define a service using a loadbalancer like nginx which then routes traffic to your containers. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7JZdyJ8qJQ